# How can I play League of Legends on EUNE using German client?

Tags: league-of-legends

I want to use LoL client that is in German, but Nordic-East server does not have the language option of German. Only West server does.

How can I change clients language to German for Nordic-East server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [official Player Support](https://support.leagueoflegends.com/entries/20159283-changing-game-language-after-installation) page formerly said you can change the game language in a configuration file. This is still the case, even though it's not mentioned anymore.

Find your LoL install directory. The instructions diverge depending on what client you're using.

**In the legacy client**, go into `RADS\system`. Open the `locale.cfg` file and change the contents to `locale = de_DE` to change it to German.

I briefly tested this on the NA client with French, and it appeared to work fully.

**In the new client**, instead of going into `RADS\system`, go into the `Config` folder. Open the `LeagueClientSettings.yaml` file. Find the line that starts with `locale:` and replace it with `locale: "de_DE"`. Be careful not to change any other lines in the file.

For more details, you can check out [this post](https://boards.na.leagueoflegends.com/en/c/help-support/HQd6vzAT-new-client-language-switching) on the boards.